# Turn a text file into a dictionary with Python

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, text

I have a text file with a pattern:

```
[Badges_373382]
Deleted=0
Button2=0 1497592154
Button1=0 1497592154
ProxReader=0
StartProc=100 1509194246 ""
NextStart=0
LastSeen=1509194246
Enabled=1
Driver=Access Control
Program=AccessProxBadge
LocChg=1509120279
Name=asd
Neuron=7F0027BF2D
Owner=373381
LostSince=1509120774
Index1=218
Photo=unknown.jpg
LastProxReader=0
Temp=0
LastTemp=0
LastMotionless=0
LastMotion=1497592154
BatteryLow=0
PrevReader=10703
Reader=357862
SuspendTill=0
SuspendSince=0
Status=1001
ConvertUponDownload=0
AXSFlags=0
Params=10106
Motion=1
USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017 4:48:15 PM
OwnerOldName=asd

[Badges_373384]
Deleted=0
Button2=0 1497538610
Button1=0 1497538610
ProxReader=0
StartProc=100 1509194246 ""
NextStart=0
LastSeen=1513872678
Enabled=1
Driver=Access Control
Program=AccessProxBadge
LocChg=1513872684
Name=dsa
Neuron=7F0027CC1C
Owner=373383
LostSince=1513872723
Index1=219
Photo=unknown.jpg
LastProxReader=0
Temp=0
LastTemp=0
LastMotionless=0
LastMotion=1497538610
BatteryLow=0
PrevReader=357874
Reader=357873
SuspendTill=0
SuspendSince=0
Status=1001
ConvertUponDownload=0
AXSFlags=0
Params=10106
Motion=1
USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017 4:48:51 PM
OwnerOldName=dsa

[Badges_373386]
Deleted=0
Button2=0 1497780768
Button1=0 1497780768
ProxReader=0
StartProc=100 1509194246 ""
NextStart=0
LastSeen=1514124910
Enabled=1
Driver=Access Control
Program=AccessProxBadge
LocChg=1514124915
Name=ss
Neuron=7F0027B5FD
Owner=373385
LostSince=1514124950
Index1=220
Photo=unknown.jpg
LastProxReader=0
Temp=0
LastTemp=0
LastMotionless=0
LastMotion=1497780768
BatteryLow=0
PrevReader=357872
Reader=357871
SuspendTill=0
SuspendSince=0
Status=1001
ConvertUponDownload=0
AXSFlags=0
Params=10106
Motion=1
USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017 4:49:24 PM
OwnerOldName=ss
```

Every new "Badge" info starts with `[Badges_number]` and end with blank line.

Using **Python 3.6**, I would like to turn this file into a dictionary so that I could easily access that information.

It should look like this:

```
content = {"Badges_373382:{"Deleted:0,.."},"Badges_371231":{"Deleted":0,..}"}
```

I'm pretty confused on how to do that, I'd love to get some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the python configparser libary

Answer (score 2):

This is basically an INI file, and Python provides the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html) module to parse such files.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('badges.ini'))

r = {section: dict(config[section]) for section in config.sections()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each line and keep track if you have seen a header in the format `[Badges_373382]`:

```
import re
import itertools
with open('filename.txt') as f:
   f = filter(lambda x:x, [i.strip('\n') for i in f])    

new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(f, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\[[a-zA-Z]+_+\d+\]', x)))] 
final_data = {new_data[i][-1][-1]:dict(c.split('=') for c in new_data[i+1][-1]) for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'[Badges_373384]': {'OwnerOldName': 'dsa', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'NextStart': '0', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'LastTemp': '0', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:48:51 PM', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1513872684', 'Reader': '357873', 'LostSince': '1513872723', 'LastMotion': '1497538610', 'Status': '1001', 'Deleted': '0', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'ProxReader': '0', 'LastSeen': '1513872678', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'Index1': '219', 'Name': 'dsa', 'Temp': '0', 'Enabled': '1', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'Motion': '1', 'Button2': '0 1497538610', 'Button1': '0 1497538610', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'PrevReader': '357874', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'Neuron': '7F0027CC1C', 'Owner': '373383', 'Params': '10106'}, '[Badges_373382]': {'OwnerOldName': 'asd', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'NextStart': '0', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'LastTemp': '0', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:48:15 PM', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1509120279', 'Reader': '357862', 'LostSince': '1509120774', 'LastMotion': '1497592154', 'Status': '1001', 'Deleted': '0', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'ProxReader': '0', 'LastSeen': '1509194246', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'Index1': '218', 'Name': 'asd', 'Temp': '0', 'Enabled': '1', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'Motion': '1', 'Button2': '0 1497592154', 'Button1': '0 1497592154', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'PrevReader': '10703', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'Neuron': '7F0027BF2D', 'Owner': '373381', 'Params': '10106'}, '[Badges_373386]': {'OwnerOldName': 'ss', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'NextStart': '0', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'LastTemp': '0', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:49:24 PM', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1514124915', 'Reader': '357871', 'LostSince': '1514124950', 'LastMotion': '1497780768', 'Status': '1001', 'Deleted': '0', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'ProxReader': '0', 'LastSeen': '1514124910', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'Index1': '220', 'Name': 'ss', 'Temp': '0', 'Enabled': '1', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'Motion': '1', 'Button2': '0 1497780768', 'Button1': '0 1497780768', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'PrevReader': '357872', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'Neuron': '7F0027B5FD', 'Owner': '373385', 'Params': '10106'}}
```

Comment: @LidorSaadVaxxor then you should mark DanGittik's response as accepted as it is beneficial for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go through each line of the file and add what you need. Their are three cases of lines you can come across:

**1.** The is a header, it will be a key final dictionary. You can just check if a line starts with `"[Badges"` here, and store the current header with a temporary variable while reading the file.

**2.** The line is a blank line, marking the end of the current badge data being read. All you need to do here is add the information collected from the current badge and add it to the dictionary, with the correct corresponding key. Depending on your implementation, you can delete these beforehand, or keep them when reading the lines.

**3.** Otherwise, the line has some info that needs to be stored. You first need to split this info on `"="`, and store it in your dictionary.

With these suggestions, you can write something like this to accomplish this task:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# dictionary of dictionary values
data = defaultdict(dict)

with open('pattern.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in file]

    # keeps track of current header
    header = None

    # case 2, deletes empty lines before hand
    valid_lines = [line for line in lines if line]

    for line in valid_lines:

        # case 1, for headers
        if line.startswith('[Badges'):

            # updates current header, and deletes square brackets
            header = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

        # case 3, data has been found
        else:

            # split and add the data
            info = line.split('=')
            key, value = info[0], info[1]
            data[header][key] = value

print(dict(data))
```

Which outputs:

```
{'Badges_373382': {'Deleted': '0', 'Button2': '0 1497592154', 'Button1': '0 1497592154', 'ProxReader': '0', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'NextStart': '0', 'LastSeen': '1509194246', 'Enabled': '1', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1509120279', 'Name': 'asd', 'Neuron': '7F0027BF2D', 'Owner': '373381', 'LostSince': '1509120774', 'Index1': '218', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Temp': '0', 'LastTemp': '0', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'LastMotion': '1497592154', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'PrevReader': '10703', 'Reader': '357862', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'Status': '1001', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'Params': '10106', 'Motion': '1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:48:15 PM', 'OwnerOldName': 'asd'}, 'Badges_373384': {'Deleted': '0', 'Button2': '0 1497538610', 'Button1': '0 1497538610', 'ProxReader': '0', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'NextStart': '0', 'LastSeen': '1513872678', 'Enabled': '1', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1513872684', 'Name': 'dsa', 'Neuron': '7F0027CC1C', 'Owner': '373383', 'LostSince': '1513872723', 'Index1': '219', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Temp': '0', 'LastTemp': '0', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'LastMotion': '1497538610', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'PrevReader': '357874', 'Reader': '357873', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'Status': '1001', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'Params': '10106', 'Motion': '1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:48:51 PM', 'OwnerOldName': 'dsa'}, 'Badges_373386': {'Deleted': '0', 'Button2': '0 1497780768', 'Button1': '0 1497780768', 'ProxReader': '0', 'StartProc': '100 1509194246 ""', 'NextStart': '0', 'LastSeen': '1514124910', 'Enabled': '1', 'Driver': 'Access Control', 'Program': 'AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg': '1514124915', 'Name': 'ss', 'Neuron': '7F0027B5FD', 'Owner': '373385', 'LostSince': '1514124950', 'Index1': '220', 'Photo': 'unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader': '0', 'Temp': '0', 'LastTemp': '0', 'LastMotionless': '0', 'LastMotion': '1497780768', 'BatteryLow': '0', 'PrevReader': '357872', 'Reader': '357871', 'SuspendTill': '0', 'SuspendSince': '0', 'Status': '1001', 'ConvertUponDownload': '0', 'AXSFlags': '0', 'Params': '10106', 'Motion': '1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate': '6/15/2017 4:49:24 PM', 'OwnerOldName': 'ss'}}
```

**Note:** The above code is just a possibility, feel free to adapt it to your needs, or even improve it.

I also used [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to add the data, since its easier to use. You can also wrap `dict()` at the end to convert it to a normal dictionary, which is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex and split the result of output:

```
pattern='^\[Badges.+?OwnerOldName=\w+'
import re
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    match=re.finditer(pattern,f.read(),re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    new=[]
    for kk in match:
        if kk.group()!='\n':
            new.append(kk.group())
    print({i.split()[0]:i.split()[1:] for i in new})
```

output:

```
  {'[Badges_373384]': ['Deleted=0', 'Button2=0', '1497538610', 'Button1=0', '1497538610', 'ProxReader=0', 'StartProc=100', '1509194246', '""', 'NextStart=0', 'LastSeen=1513872678', 'Enabled=1', 'Driver=Access', 'Control', 'Program=AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg=1513872684', 'Name=dsa', 'Neuron=7F0027CC1C', 'Owner=373383', 'LostSince=1513872723', 'Index1=219', 'Photo=unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader=0', 'Temp=0', 'LastTemp=0', 'LastMotionless=0', 'LastMotion=1497538610', 'BatteryLow=0', 'PrevReader=357874', 'Reader=357873', 'SuspendTill=0', 'SuspendSince=0', 'Status=1001', 'ConvertUponDownload=0', 'AXSFlags=0', 'Params=10106', 'Motion=1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017', '4:48:51', 'PM', 'OwnerOldName=dsa'], '[Badges_373382]': ['Deleted=0', 'Button2=0', '1497592154', 'Button1=0', '1497592154', 'ProxReader=0', 'StartProc=100', '1509194246', '""', 'NextStart=0', 'LastSeen=1509194246', 'Enabled=1', 'Driver=Access', 'Control', 'Program=AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg=1509120279', 'Name=asd', 'Neuron=7F0027BF2D', 'Owner=373381', 'LostSince=1509120774', 'Index1=218', 'Photo=unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader=0', 'Temp=0', 'LastTemp=0', 'LastMotionless=0', 'LastMotion=1497592154', 'BatteryLow=0', 'PrevReader=10703', 'Reader=357862', 'SuspendTill=0', 'SuspendSince=0', 'Status=1001', 'ConvertUponDownload=0', 'AXSFlags=0', 'Params=10106', 'Motion=1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017', '4:48:15', 'PM', 'OwnerOldName=asd'], '[Badges_373386]': ['Deleted=0', 'Button2=0', '1497780768', 'Button1=0', '1497780768', 'ProxReader=0', 'StartProc=100', '1509194246', '""', 'NextStart=0', 'LastSeen=1514124910', 'Enabled=1', 'Driver=Access', 'Control', 'Program=AccessProxBadge', 'LocChg=1514124915', 'Name=ss', 'Neuron=7F0027B5FD', 'Owner=373385', 'LostSince=1514124950', 'Index1=220', 'Photo=unknown.jpg', 'LastProxReader=0', 'Temp=0', 'LastTemp=0', 'LastMotionless=0', 'LastMotion=1497780768', 'BatteryLow=0', 'PrevReader=357872', 'Reader=357871', 'SuspendTill=0', 'SuspendSince=0', 'Status=1001', 'ConvertUponDownload=0', 'AXSFlags=0', 'Params=10106', 'Motion=1', 'USER_DATA_CreationDate=6/15/2017', '4:49:24', 'PM', 'OwnerOldName=ss']}
```